# Sending e-mail from a Custom SQL Server Reporting Services Delivery Extension

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I've developed my own delivery extension for Reporting Services 2005, to integrate this with our SaaS marketing solution.

It takes the subscription, and takes a snapshot of the report with a custom set of parameters. It then renders the report, sends an e-mail with a link and the report attached as XLS.

Everything works fine, until mail delivery...

Here's my code for sending e-mail:

```
 public static List<string> SendMail(SubscriptionData data, Stream reportStream, string reportName, string smptServerHostname, int smtpServerPort)
{
  List<string> failedRecipients = new List<string>();

  MailMessage emailMessage = new MailMessage(data.ReplyTo, data.To);
  emailMessage.Priority = data.Priority;
  emailMessage.Subject = data.Subject;
  emailMessage.IsBodyHtml = false;
  emailMessage.Body = data.Comment;

  if (reportStream != null)
  {
    Attachment reportAttachment = new Attachment(reportStream, reportName);
    emailMessage.Attachments.Add(reportAttachment);
    reportStream.Dispose();
  }

  try
  {
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(smptServerHostname, smtpServerPort);

    // Send the MailMessage
    smtp.Send(emailMessage);
  }
  catch (SmtpFailedRecipientsException ex)
  {
    // Delivery failed for the recipient. Add the e-mail address to the failedRecipients List
    failedRecipients.Add(ex.FailedRecipient);
  }
  catch (SmtpFailedRecipientException ex)
  {
    // Delivery failed for the recipient. Add the e-mail address to the failedRecipients List
    failedRecipients.Add(ex.FailedRecipient);
  }
  catch (SmtpException ex)
  {
    throw ex;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    throw ex;
  }

  // Return the List of failed recipient e-mail addresses, so the client can maintain its list.
  return failedRecipients;
}
```

Values for SmtpServerHostname is localhost, and port is 25.

I veryfied that I can actually send mail, by using Telnet. And it works.

**Here's the error message I get from SSRS:**

ReportingServicesService!notification!4!08/28/2008-11:26:17:: Notification 6ab32b8d-296e-47a2-8d96-09e81222985c completed.  Success: False, Status: Exception Message: Failure sending mail. Stacktrace:    at MyDeliveryExtension.MailDelivery.SendMail(SubscriptionData data, Stream reportStream, String reportName, String smptServerHostname, Int32 smtpServerPort) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CustomReporting\MyDeliveryExtension\MailDelivery.cs:line 48
   at MyDeliveryExtension.MyDelivery.Deliver(Notification notification) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CustomReporting\MyDeliveryExtension\MyDelivery.cs:line 153, DeliveryExtension: My Delivery, Report: Clicks Development, Attempt 1
ReportingServicesService!dbpolling!4!08/28/2008-11:26:17:: NotificationPolling finished processing item 6ab32b8d-296e-47a2-8d96-09e81222985c

**Could this have something to do with Trust/Code Access Security?**

My delivery extension is granted full trust in rssrvpolicy.config:

```
   <CodeGroup 
    class="UnionCodeGroup"
    version="1"
    PermissionSetName="FullTrust"
    Name="MyDelivery_CodeGroup"
    Description="Code group for MyDelivery extension">
    <IMembershipCondition class="UrlMembershipCondition" version="1" Url="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.2\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin\MyDeliveryExtension.dll" />
   </CodeGroup>
```

Could trust be an issue here?

Another theory: SQL Server and SSRS was installed in the security context of Local System. Am I right, or is this service account restricted access to any network resource? Even its own SMTP Server?

I tried changing all SQL Server Services logons to Administrator - but still without any success.

I also tried logging onto the SMTP server in my code, by proviiding: NetworkCredential("Administrator", "password") and also NetworkCredential("Administrator", "password", "MyRepServer")

Can anyone help here, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's at:

```
at MyDeliveryExtension.MailDelivery.SendMail(SubscriptionData data, Stream reportStream, String reportName, String smptServerHostname, Int32 smtpServerPort) 
  in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CustomReporting\MyDeliveryExtension\MailDelivery.cs:line 48 

at MyDeliveryExtension.MyDelivery.Deliver(Notification notification) 
  in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CustomReporting\MyDeliveryExtension\MyDelivery.cs:line 153
```

Also you seem to be disposing the report stream, but that should be done by whatever opened that stream, not your method (it won't be obvious that attaching a stream disposes it).

You're losing part of your stack trace due to how you re-throw exceptions. Don't throw the ex variable, just throw is enough.

Try this tweak:

```
public static List<string> SendMail(SubscriptionData data, Stream reportStream, string reportName, string smptServerHostname, int smtpServerPort)
{
  List<string> failedRecipients = new List<string>();

  MailMessage emailMessage = new MailMessage(data.ReplyTo, data.To) {
      Priority = data.Priority,
      Subject = data.Subject,
      IsBodyHtml = false,
      Body = data.Comment
  };

  if (reportStream != null)
    emailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(reportStream, reportName));

  try
  {
      SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(smptServerHostname, smtpServerPort);

      // Send the MailMessage
      smtp.Send(emailMessage);
  }
  catch (SmtpFailedRecipientsException ex)
  {
    // Delivery failed for the recipient. Add the e-mail address to the failedRecipients List
    failedRecipients.Add(ex.FailedRecipient);

    //are you missing a loop here? only one failed address will ever be returned
  }
  catch (SmtpFailedRecipientException ex)
  {
    // Delivery failed for the recipient. Add the e-mail address to the failedRecipients List
    failedRecipients.Add(ex.FailedRecipient);
  }

  // Return the List of failed recipient e-mail addresses, so the client can maintain its list.
  return failedRecipients;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to remove the reportStream Attachment:

```
  //if (reportStream != null)    
     //emailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(reportStream, reportName));
```

And now it works fine.

So it is something to do with the reportStream.

Answer (score 0):

After fooling around with the tunctionallity that gets the reportStream, I was able to fix the mail sending problem.

The error wasn't in the SendMail method, but somewehere else. The exception was thrown in the context, of SendMail though. Buggered!

Answer (score 0):

That's why you have to avoid:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

As that basically cloaks your exception in a new one.

If you use:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw; //note: no ex
}
```

It keeps the original exception and stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

```
FileStream m_fileStream = null;

m_files = notification.Report.Render(format, null);
RenderedOutputFile m_renderedOutputFile = m_files[0];
m_fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
m_renderedOutputFile.Data.Seek((long)0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
byte[] arr = new byte[(int)m_renderedOutputFile.Data.Length + 1];

m_renderedOutputFile.Data.Read(arr, 0, (int)m_renderedOutputFile.Data.Length);

m_fileStream.Write(arr, 0, (int)m_renderedOutputFile.Data.Length);

m_fileStream.Close();
```